# How can I remove button of ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview, expand

I've used a custom `ExpandableListAdapter` in my project. How can I remove this button?
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In XML

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

or in code

```
expListView.setGroupIndicator(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use this:
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" ?

I don't know why you want to remove this button, but for some cases my advise can be useful.